# validation password strong using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I trying validate password and the conditions are

**1-** A-a

**2-** 0- 9

**3-** Special characters

The first and second conditions work fine with this expression

```
(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,16})$
```

But i dont know implement the third condition.

**My Method**

```
public static boolean PasswordStrong(String pass) {
    String expresion = "(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,16})$";
    Pattern patron = Pattern.compile(expresion);
    Matcher m = patron.matcher(pass);
    if (m.find())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You can do more than one match. You don't have to do all in just one match.

Comment: @AlexanderCampos i  solved my problem whit this expression                ((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved again my question >.<

i use this expression

```
((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})
```

more examples you can find with [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/10-java-regular-expression-examples-you-should-know/)